# Enable Code Analysis on Build is false but still validate code with rules

Tags: visual-studio-2015, code-analysis

In project properties I am not selecting Enable Code Analysis on Build check box, but still getting error on compile from code analysis rule.
Why I am getting errors from rule set even Enable Code Analysis on Build is not selected?

Currently I am working on CS8019 rule and facing this issue in only Visual Studio 2015. Same thing works correctly in Visual Studio 2013.

Comment: Please try to create a [mcve] *and* [edit] your question to show us some code and tell us *what* code analysis error(s) you're getting. At the moment, your question is effectively "guess what's going on with my code (that I'm not going to show you)?"

Comment: CS is a C# error or warning, not a code analysis one (Code Analysis rules start with CA).

Comment: That's correct. But I have change action from warning to error.

Comment: So, is there even a question here then? You're getting that warning because it's a C# compiler warning, **not** an analysis rule. Thus, the "Enable Code Analysis" setting has no effect.

Comment: I have change the action of CS8019 to error. But in my case above situation works with Visual studio 2013 but gives compile time error in Visual studio 2015.